# icCube printing dashboards with custom widgets

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I've some troubles printing custom made widgets on top of icCube. Is there a special way to make custom widgets, created with e.g. D3, printable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `isRendered()` method in every widget, it should return `true` only after widget is actually rendered otherwise it is possible that it won't be rendered in pdf.

Comment: Thanks. Will forward that to my developer.